# Select different shade of colors from image c#

Tags: c#, gdi

How we can differentiate `Color` by its shades. Means suppose if there are 20 colors in image. 10 colors are with blue `shade` including blue and 10 with green `shade` including green. Then i want to select 2 from them blue and green, filtered the same shade colors. How can i do this in c#?

Comment: See if shade is HUE or something else first and try to include a picture in the question - it will help someone help you.

Comment: I am trying to give user a facility to change the image colors, now i have to show the image color pallete from which user will select any color and change with any other color. The problem is when i am reading the color pallete , it contains same shade colors ( #FFFFFF, #FFFFF0, #FFFFF1 ) these all are white colors with little difference but for user these all are white colors. So that`s why i want to filtered all the same shade color and show user only one white color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the color scale(0-255) for the 3 primary colors, and set ranges for each to account for shades, then you could scan the pixels of the image, and allocate each one into a color category, where it would have multiple shades of the color, within a range specified by you.